How to create a custom function in `sql/install.sql` script?
I’m trying to create a custom function in MySQL by adding it to the sql/install.sql script. My goal is to compare two JSON arrays and return a boolean indicating whether the arrays have any overlapping elements. The function should work similarly to an "array overlap" operation.
Here’s the sql/install.sql script I’m using:
CREATE FUNCTION IF NOT EXISTS JSON_OVERLAPS_5_7(json_array1 JSON, json_array2 JSON)
RETURNS BOOLEAN
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE n INT;
    DECLARE current_element JSON;
    
    -- Get the length of the second array
    SET n = JSON_LENGTH(json_array2);

    -- Loop through each element of json_array2
    WHILE i < n DO
        -- Extract each element from json_array2
        SET current_element = JSON_EXTRACT(json_array2, CONCAT('$[', i, ']'));
        
        -- Check if the element exists in json_array1
        IF JSON_CONTAINS(json_array1, current_element) THEN
            -- If a match is found, return TRUE
            RETURN TRUE;
        END IF;
        
        -- Increment index
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;

    -- If no matches are found, return FALSE
    RETURN FALSE;
END;

When running the script (package installation), I’ve tried using it both with and without the DELIMITER $$ statement, but it still errors out. Any insights into what I'm doing wrong or how to fix this would be greatly appreciated!
Edit: Using script.php also does not work since all queries are now prepared and CREATE FUNCTION does not support it.

This is happening because Joomla's extension installer splits SQL into separate queries at the semicolon and setting a custom delimiter is not supported. Though such a feature would very useful.
Running this query inside install script is possible. This should work on MySQL PDO driver out of the box (YMMV). But for MySQLi driver you have to get the underlying MySQLi connection from Joomla's database object to run unprepared statements:
$connection = $db->getConnection();
$connection->query($sql);

There is also Joomla\Database\Mysqli\MysqliDriver::executeUnpreparedQuery() method but it's protected. You'd have to extend/decorate the class or use something like Closure or Reflection to access it:
$executeQuery = Closure::bind(fn(string $sql) => $this->executeUnpreparedQuery($sql), $db, $db);
$executeQuery($sql);


Thanks for the answer! I solved this issue by decorating the class, however your solution with Closure::bind is interesting, I will check it out! It's a bummer that Joomla 4 don't have an interface to run unprepared queries. Not all queries are supported in a prepared context.
